# I want to learn about diophantine analysis

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, book-recommendation

I'm thinking about learning diophantine analysis, it is a subject that seems pretty interesting to me, I have some background on number theory and know the basics about diphantine equations, such as linear diophantine equations or Pell's equation; besides, I've worked with continued fractions and feel comfortable around them; what book would you recommend me to learn more about this subject?

Answer (score 3):

Jorn Steuding, Diophantine Analysis.
Ed Burger, Exploring the Number Jungle: A Journey into Diophantine Analysis.
Ed Burger and Robert Tubbs, Making Transcendence Transparent.
Nigel Smart, The Algorithmic Resolution of Diophantine Equations.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into them! What are the main differences between one book and another?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes.  Anyone can google "books on diophantine analysis."  You should really describe them.

Comment: @Dzoooks, anyone can type those titles and authors into Google and get to the publishers' pages, which will generally have a table of contents and a blurb indicating the level of the book, maybe even a chapter or two freely available; also, Google may lead you to reviews of the books. Maybe you would like to do that, and summarize what you find as an answer here. FWIW, I didn't find those books on Google, I found them in my "office".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your answer isn't helpful.

Comment: @Dzoooks, you are welcome to edit it to improve it, or to post a better answer yourself.